# How to mint one NFT with Alchemy and Sepolia?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, smartcontracts, nft

I'm having an issue when trying to mint an NFT using Alchemy. I followed the steps provided in the documentation and everything works fine when using Sepolia, but when I try to run the node script/mint.js command, I get the following error message:

```
something went wrong Error: server response 404 Not Found (request={  }, response={  }, error=null, code=SERVER_ERROR, version=6.3.0)  
    at makeError (.../ethereum/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:121:21)  
    at assert (.../ethereum/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:138:15)  
    at FetchResponse.assertOk (.../ethereum/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/fetch.js:775:32)  
    at AlchemyProvider._send (.../ethereum/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:772:18)  
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)  
    at async .../ethereum/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:239:40 {  
  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',  
  request: FetchRequest {},  
  response: FetchResponse {},  
  error: undefined  
}.
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. I've included my mint.js file below for reference:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/avatar.sol/avatar.json");  
const contractInterface = contract.abi;

const provider = new ethers.AlchemyProvider("sepolia", process.env.API_URL);

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

const Avatar = new ethers.Contract(process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS, contractInterface, wallet);

const main = async () => {  
    try {  
      const transaction = await Avatar.mint(process.env.PUBLIC_KEY);  
      console.log(transaction);  
    } catch (e) {  
      console.log("something went wrong", e);  
    }  
};

main();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have imported ethers to make sure to have the AlchemyProvider imported. I checked my API_URL and I ask chatGPT to help me many times but can't find a solution.

My goal is to ruproperly run node script/mint.js without any conflicts

Comment: What is your process.env.API_URL value? can you console log it? Because it say 404 so may be it is wrong. If possible, console.log every ENV you use so you can ensure that you use the URL as your expectation